# Como posso automatizar um dowload de um arquivo excel na web?

Tags: java, python, microsoft-excel

Ola pessoal estou com um problema, queria automatizar uma rotina daria que baixa um arquivo Excel num certo site, se possível usando Python ou java, queria saber se já existe um programa/código que faça isso se não como posso automatizar isso?

obs: eu preciso selecionar data antes para fazer o download do arquivo e uma opção do tipo do arquivo se e pdf ou xls